# Solving a set of linear algebraic equations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have the following $n$ linear equations with $n$ variables that are in a linear format but I have not found any systematic algorithm for solving them.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1  & x_2  & x_3 \\ 
x_2 & x_3 & x_4\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\ 
x_{n-1} & x_n & x_1\\ 
x_n & x_1 & x_2
\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \\ 
\beta \\
\gamma 
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
e_1\\ 
e_2\\ 
e_3\\ 
\vdots \\
e_n  
\end{bmatrix}
$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $e_i$ are constants and the unknown variables are the $n \times 1$ vector consisting of $x_i$.
How can I find the $x_i$ using a systematic approach?

Comment: Why not just re-write in the form $Ax = b$? (where the rows of $A$ are shifts of $[\alpha, \beta, \gamma, 0, \ldots, 0]$)

Comment: You will end up with a circulant matrix once you write the problem as $Ax=b$ and there are systematic approaches to solve those problems,

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to the system
$$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta & \gamma & & & & \\ & \alpha & \beta & \gamma & & & \\& & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & & \\ & & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \\ & & & & \alpha& \beta& \gamma \\  \gamma& & & &  & \alpha& \beta  \\  \beta& \gamma& & & && \alpha\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\\vdots  \\ x_{n-1} \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}e_1 \\ e_2 \\ \vdots \\\vdots  \\ e_{n-1} \\ e_n \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: this is really clever